# Converting ActiveRecord::Result to ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

I have running an SQL query, which ends up returning * from table ABC.
I am running this in my ruby on rails code by below command:
query:

```
sql = select * from ABC WHERE <condition>

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

I am getting the outputs as results which is of type ActiveRecord::Result
This, I am converting to an array, by using function to_hash provided by ActiveRecord::Result. However, this is an array of Hashes.
Is there a way in which I can convert it to an array of ActiveRecord's
(I need to do further processing with each active record)
For ex: single_result.outdated? (where outdated is a field belonging to another table DEF which is connected to table ABC via single_result.id)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You *could* do a `map` and instantiate each item - but that seems super wasteful. I assume there is a reason you're using the `sql` approach instead of a regular record query (which would return a collection of records)?

Comment: You should try and use `ActiveRecord` query methods to perform queries to your db unless you *have* to go by `sql` approach. As mentioned above that way you would get a collection of `activerecord` objects which then you would be able to iterate and call any attribute or method on each one.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I, indeed am using the sql approach as I cannot go with the traditional approach (implementation details) .So, there is no other way other than just instantiating each item? (Please Note, that I must use an sql query only and not any ActiveRecord function :))

Comment: `entities = Entity.find_by_sql('select * from entities where id > 0')` will give you an Array of AR objects.